# preg_replace case insensitive using two arrays to replace the first match

Tags: php, regex, arrays, replace, uppercase

I need something like this:

```
$string = "That's a big apple, a red apple";
$arr = array(apple, lemon);
$arr2 = array(APPLE, LEMON);
preg_replace('/($arr)/i', $arr2, $string, 1);
//output = That's a big APPLE, a red apple
```

It means replace words for uppercase using arrays but only the first match, case-insensitive.

Comment: Can you provide this in the form of sample input vs expected output?

Comment: Did you hear about the functuin `mb_strtoupper` ?

Comment: Shouldn't there be `$arr = array('apple', 'lemon')` and `$arr2 = array('APPLE', 'LEMON')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first variable is not correct, if its an array each value needs to be a regex

```
$arr = array('/\b(apple)\b/i', '/\b(lemon)\b/i');
$arr2 = array('APPLE', 'LEMON');

preg_replace($arr, $arr2, $string, 1);
```

Edit: I updated this to include word boundries which may help in some instances

Comment: Please do not forget to use [preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) on data included to a pattern.

Comment: it works for matching with $string = (This /apple/ is a /pink apple/), right?

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`strtr()`](http://php.net/strtr) instead of a regex:

```
$string = "That's a big apple, a red apple";
$string = strtr( $string, array( 'apple' => 'APPLE', 'lemon' => 'LEMON'));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your code.

- you need to quote the strings inside your array; otherwise, PHP will try to interpret them as constants
- you can't just put the `$arr` variable in the regex string, you would need to loop through the array and use the string value of the array item in the `preg_replace`
- `preg_replace` will replace all occurrences of regex

If you only want to replace the first occurs of the string you could try a combination of `strpos` and `substr_replace`

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "That's a big apple, a red apple.";
$words = array('APPLE', 'LEMON');
foreach ($words as $word){
    $ini = stristr($string, $word, TRUE);
    if ($ini){
        $string = $ini.$word.substr($string, strlen($ini.$word));
        break;
    }
}
echo $string;
```

Output:

**That's a big APPLE, a red apple.**

Comment: i cant change the string for lowercase cuz i need to keep formating

Comment: @EddieD. - My new and improved version.